# How to know when people starred my repo on github?

Tags: github, history

I am working on this for few days, and I can't find any solution.
I tried to call the github API to have these informations, but it seems like it's impossible to know when people have starred my repo? Like you know, to get a history of that, month by month.

Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question for stackexchange.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer for this

Answer (score 2):

I believe Github will automatically display (on the feed in your landing page when you visit Github.com) a note when someone stars or watches your repository

Comment: As of today, this has been moved to the "Following" tab in the [GitHub Dashboard](https://github.com/dashboard) page when you sign-in.